# Filter model based on checked checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple EntityFramework model that I'm trying to filter by using checkboxes.

My model contains 2 properties:

```
public class Company
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to:

1. Show an index view of all the companies in the database
2. Show a list of checkboxes corresponding to each of the distinct locations of the companies
3. Allow a user to select one or more of the checkboxes and submit the form to redisplay the index with the filter to locations applied.

I'm not sure how best to approach this - I think I need a viewmodel of my Companies and locations, but I'm not sure how to display the list of checkboxes and then filter by them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an `IsSelected` property along with your Company and Location properties. Your checkboxes should be wired to those. Then when a user submits the form, your model will pick up these values. You can just filter your data based on IsSelected being true and return the matching rows.

**Edit** to show an example. Quickly tested with IE since it's such an aggressive cache monster:

A quick note. It's late and I'm tired. Take the concept but think more clearly about your objects and storage. This is a working example only.

First, a ViewModel:

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And the Get and Post actions in the controller:

```
static IList<CompanyModel> CompanyList = null;

public ActionResult Company()
{
    if (CompanyList == null)
    {
        CompanyList = new List<CompanyModel>()
        {
            new CompanyModel() { Name = "Company 1", Location = "Boston" },
            new CompanyModel() { Name = "Company 2", Location = "New York" },
            new CompanyModel() { Name = "Company 3", Location = "Chicago" },
            new CompanyModel() { Name = "Company 4", Location = "Austin" }
        };
    }

    return View(CompanyList);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Company(CompanyModel[] companies)
{
    CompanyList = companies.Where(c => c.IsSelected).ToList();
    return RedirectToAction("Company");
}
```

This demonstrates the Post, Redirect, Get pattern to ensure the browser doesn't display incorrect results from caching and won't lead to undesired behavior if the user refreshes the screen which would re-submit the original form.

Now the view using the scaffold code for an Edit screen:

```
@model IList<MVCEditorTemplateDemo.Models.CompanyModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Company";
}

<h2>Company</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CompanyModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Location, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Location)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Location)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please expand on what you mean by wiring my checkboxes to the is selected property? Is this in the view model? Because I need to create a checkbox for each location, and I don't know what locations will be retrieved

Comment: You create a View Model that has some sort of IEnumerable<> of objects that have the info you need for your form. This would include Company, Location and IsSelected. In your View, you use the HTML helpers to do a `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)`. Then when you submit, your model will be wired up with the properties populated and you can then filter as needed.

Comment: Any chance you can post an example?

Comment: Threw together something real quick and edited my answer. Apologize for any readability issues - I was seconds away from shutting down for the night!